# Paying for page charges after a grant ends

Tags: publications, funding

Often publications resulting from funded research are published after the grant ends. It seems nowadays more and more publishers are requiring fees (submission fees, page charges, and open access fees). How does one pay for these fees after a grant ends?

Comment: You did the work, choose a journal that do not charge the authors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it works here in Japan, is that each professor has an amount of money called "discretionary spending", from there, they get money for these kinds of things. And is usual that if a professor has his name in the paper , he should use part of this money to pay for the submission.

That money does not comes form a grant, but the University's endowment, so I guess it depends on that.

Answer (score 1):

**I refuse to publish in a journal that charges me for publishing my years of sweat and labour for their financial gain and asks me for money as well. Its against my principles.**

Once I was asked to pay 500 dollars for color pictures. I asked them to revert them back to black and white and just have them in colour online.

Open access is a different story and I see it as being legitimate on their part to ask for money for it. It you don't have the grant money => no open access. Put a preprint somewhere and publish somewhere that allows preprints or at least turns a blind eye.

Comment: This may not be viewed as an option. If a given field recognizes a particular journal as prestigious, then it will directly hurt the researcher's professional standing to abstain from publishing because of moral stance.

Comment: There may be prestigious journals in a field that have this kind of behavior. I don't know I have academically been raised to refuse to accept such practices and I believe in the principle. I have seen two of my mentors reject such practices and that has affected me as well. If I have to make the choice between the more prestigious journal (I doubt that all of them have such behavior in any given filed) I will choose to stick to my principle.

Comment: While I may not personally want to support such publishing policies, I think it is unfair to my funders to not publish in the place that will have the largest "impact" (and I don't mean impact factor).